# Identify date format in jquery and set it as default in a jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

// I have installmentDate which is an object object

```
var installmentDate = installment.installmentDate;                                     
alert(JSON.stringify(installmentDate));
```

Using JSON.stringify(installmentDate) it shows

> `{"date":3, "day":5, "hours":0, "minutes":0, "month":9, "nanos":0, "seconds":0, "time":1412274600000, "timezoneoffset":-330, "year":114}`

Please identify in which format this is in.
And I am trying to set this date as default to a jquery datepicker
These are the following ways I tried and nothing works

```
$('#dueDate').datepicker('setDate', installmentDate);
$('#dueDate').datepicker('setDate', new Date((installment.installmentDate));
$('#dueDate').val(installmentDate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date does not have the proper format. According to the documentation, here are the possible options:

> The new date may be a Date object or a string in the current date
>   format (e.g., "01/26/2009"), a number of days from today (e.g., +7) or
>   a string of values and periods ("y" for years, "m" for months, "w" for
>   weeks, "d" for days, e.g., "+1m +7d"), or null to clear the selected
>   date.

You might need to reformat your `installmentDate`.

Comment: Are there ways to reformat the installmentDate?. I am getting it from an ajax function.

Comment: You can always call the different attributes from the JSON directly and format it properly (installmentDate.date, installmentDate.day, installmentDate.hours etc.. ).